# Graph db: how to trigger on event?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

We are looking to store Windows process tree information in a graph database.

We have an endpoint detection tool that collects process creation and deletion information. For example, the process id, the command that started the process, the parent process and so on.

The data will be loaded into the graph database in real-time.

Is there a way in Neo4j to trigger an event anytime we see "iexplore.exe" as the parent of processes such as "powershell.exe" or "cmd.exe"? In some cases, there may be several other processes between iexplore and powershell/cmd.

For example: the attacker exploits a vulnerability in IE, drops of a file on disk, executes it, and then uses `powershell.exe`.

Does graph databases provide us the ability to build in rules to capture more complex events like that?

Comment: Your opinion on what is the "best" graph database" (and why you're choosing one specific brand) is really not relevant. Nor is asking for recommendations on alternative tools (tool / product / service recommendation questions are off-topic). I edited that stuff out of your question.

Comment: Regarding the question itself: Neo4j has no way of notifying you of an OS-level process. You'd need some type of process monitoring app/tool to do that. At least, that seems like the question you're asking. Maybe that's an incorrect interpretation. Probably would help if you edited your question to clarify.

Comment: What action should the trigger perform?

Comment: David Makogon, We have an endpoint software collecting the data. That's mentioned in the second sentence.

Comment: stdob, Firing an API call to inform us would be useful. Or sending us an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apoc triggers`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers) for set trigger and [`apoc.es.postRaw`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_interacting_with_elastic_search)  for external API call. For example:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
        'iexplorer',
        'MATCH (P:Process {name:"iexplore.exe"})-[:parent_of*]->(C:Process)
           WHERE C.name IN ["powershell.exe", "cmd.exe"]
         WITH collect(distinct id(P)) as ids
         CALL apoc.es.postRaw("http://localhost", "neo4jevent", ids)  yield value
         RETURN value',
         '{phase:'after'}'
)
```